# VB.NET: "AddHandler" by specifying Handler function as a variable

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I'm writing an add-in for Autodesk Inventor (a 3D CAD program). The add-in adds a bunch of internal commands to Inventor, and creates a toolbar button for each command. I need to connect the Execute event for each of those commands to a handler function in my add-in.

I've created a "MyCommand" class, which contains all of the information necessary to define the command. I've also created a List(Of MyCommand) with the definitions for each command. Finally, I can iterate through each command and create the internal Inventor command definition, as well as add the button to the toolbar. However, what I can't figure out how to do is associate the command with its Handler function *within the loop*.

The example code below illustrates what I'm after:

```vb
Sub CreateCommands()
    Dim oCommands As New List(Of MyCommand)

    oCommands.Add(New MyCommand("DrawLogoCmd", "Draw Logo", "DrawLogoSub"))
    oCommands.Add(New MyCommand("PublishDrawingCmd", "Publish Drawing", "PublishDrawingSub"))
    ' [Dozens more commands]

    For Each oCommand As MyCommand In oCommands
        ' Code for adding internal command definition and button to Inventor. This is working fine.
        Dim oCommandDef As Inventor.CommandDefinition = InventorApp.CommandDefinitions.Add(oCommand.InternalDefinitionName, oCommand.DisplayName)
        InventorApp.ToolbarButtons.Add(oCommandDef)

        ' Associate command definition with handler function
        ' ===== THIS IS THE LINE I NEED TO FIGURE OUT =====
        AddHandler oCommandDef.OnExecute, AddressOf oCommand.HandlerSubName
    Next
End Sub

Sub DrawLogoSub()
    ' [My add-in's code to draw logo in Inventor]
End Sub

Sub PublishDrawingSub()
    ' [My add-in's code to publish drawing in Inventor]
End Sub

Class MyCommand
    Public InternalDefinitionName As String
    Public DisplayName As String
    Public HandlerSubName As String

    Sub New(InternalDefinitionName As String, DisplayName As String, HandlerSubName As String)
        With Me
            .InternalDefinitionName = InternalDefinitionName
            .DisplayName = DisplayName
            .HandlerSubName = HandlerSubName
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

So, is this possible? Is there some way to get the "AddressOf" my function using its name as a string? Or, is there some way to store a reference to the function itself in my MyCommand class, and pass that to the AddressOf operator?

Or, is there some other way besides "AddHandler/AddressOf" that might work?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could find the method by name using reflection, but I wouldn't recommend it.  The `AddHandler` command is usually given the `AddressOf` a method, but it can also take a delegate, as long as it conforms to the event's signature.  So, unless you have some need to do it by string, I would recommend doing something like this instead.  Assuming that the event matches the normal `EventHandler` delegate:

```
Sub CreateCommands()
    Dim oCommands As New List(Of MyCommand)

    oCommands.Add(New MyCommand("DrawLogoCmd", "Draw Logo", AddressOf DrawLogo))
    oCommands.Add(New MyCommand("PublishDrawingCmd", "Publish Drawing", AddressOf PublishDrawing))
    ' [Dozens more commands]

    For Each oCommand As MyCommand In oCommands
        ' Code for adding internal command definition and button to Inventor. This is working fine.
        Dim oCommandDef As Inventor.CommandDefinition = InventorApp.CommandDefinitions.Add(oCommand.InternalDefinitionName, oCommand.DisplayName)
        InventorApp.ToolbarButtons.Add(oCommandDef)

        ' Associate command definition with handler function
        AddHandler oCommandDef.OnExecute, oCommand.Handler
    Next
End Sub

Sub DrawLogo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' [My add-in's code to draw logo in Inventor]
End Sub

Sub PublishDrawing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' [My add-in's code to publish drawing in Inventor]
End Sub

Class MyCommand
    Public InternalDefinitionName As String
    Public DisplayName As String
    Public Handler As EventHandler

    Sub New(InternalDefinitionName As String, DisplayName As String, Handler As EventHandler)
        With Me
            .InternalDefinitionName = InternalDefinitionName
            .DisplayName = DisplayName
            .Handler = Handler
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you really need to do it by string, you could use reflection like this (note that I used `NameOf` rather than hard-coding the method names as string literals, just to make it safer):

```
Sub CreateCommands()
    Dim oCommands As New List(Of MyCommand)

    oCommands.Add(New MyCommand("DrawLogoCmd", "Draw Logo", NameOf(DrawLogo)))
    oCommands.Add(New MyCommand("PublishDrawingCmd", "Publish Drawing", NameOf(PublishDrawing)))
    ' [Dozens more commands]

    For Each oCommand As MyCommand In oCommands
        ' Code for adding internal command definition and button to Inventor. This is working fine.
        Dim oCommandDef As Inventor.CommandDefinition = InventorApp.CommandDefinitions.Add(oCommand.InternalDefinitionName, oCommand.DisplayName)
        InventorApp.ToolbarButtons.Add(oCommandDef)

        ' Associate command definition with handler function
        AddHandler oCommandDef.OnExecute, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) CallMethod(oCommand.Handler)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CallMethod(name As String)
    Me.GetType().GetMethod(name).Invoke(Me, Nothing)
End Sub

Sub DrawLogo()
    ' [My add-in's code to draw logo in Inventor]
End Sub

Sub PublishDrawing()
    ' [My add-in's code to publish drawing in Inventor]
End Sub
```

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks. I'm trying the first one but on the `AddHandler oCommandDef.OnExecute, oCommand.Handler` line, the `oCommand.Handler` portion gives the following error: "Value of type 'EventHandler' cannot be converted to 'ButtonDefinitionSink_OnExecuteEventHandler'.". I tried using that "Sink" type instead of "EventHandler" but it's not defined. And I can't find any documentation on it, whether in the vb.net documentation or Inventor. Any ideas?

Comment: Search for it in the Object Browser.  It's got to be a custom delegate type exposed as a public type in one of the Audodesk libraries.  If you can't find it, look at the definition of the `OnExecute` event in the `Inventor.CommandDefinition` class and it should show you the fully qualified name for it.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the Object Browser directly under the Inventor node. I'm not sure why it's listed there but IntelliSense wouldn't bring it up.... Anyway, it looks like this is going to work (or, at least, compile). I'll post back here if it functions properly. In the meantime, could you explain why you don't recommend using reflection? What kinds of issues or undesirable behavior could result?

Comment: Reflection circumvents the compiler's type checking.  In other words, if you changed the name of the method, but forgot to change the string literal, it would still compile fine, but it would throw an exception at run-time.

Comment: IT'S WORKING! I'm thrilled. This will make adding commands and buttons so much easier. I had to tweak one or two other things, such as adding `WithEvents` to the `oCommands` declaration. But after that I'm able to add multiple buttons simply by defining their internal name, display name, and handler sub. Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want code to map the string to the method reference. I'm not 100% clear on the syntax any more, but it could look something like this:

```
Dim actionMap As Dictionary(Of string, Action(Of Object, EventArgs))
actionMap.Add("DrawLogo", AddressOf DrawLogo)
actionmap.Add("PublishDrawing", AddressOf PublishDrawing)
```

And then the `For Each` loop could use the dictionary like this:

```
For Each oCommand As MyCommand In oCommands
    Dim oCommandDef As Inventor.CommandDefinition = InventorApp.CommandDefinitions.Add(oCommand.InternalDefinitionName, oCommand.DisplayName)
    InventorApp.ToolbarButtons.Add(oCommandDef)

    AddHandler oCommandDef.OnExecute, actionMap(oCommand.HandlerSubName)
Next
```

---

While I'm here, I'll add in the move from VB6/VBScript to .Net, Microsoft changed their style guidelines for VB. Instead of recommending hungarian warts like `o`, they now specifically recommend **against** those warts, based on the way .Net uses types more strongly and the better tooling support. The prefixes just don't add the value they used to, and now instead of `oCommand`, you can now just write `command`, which tends to be much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the Dictionary suggestion. Steven's suggestion requires less overhead, so I'm going to follow that through first. If it doesn't work, I'll try the Dictionary.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about the "warts". I like to stick with standards when I can. So you're saying even if I have a type called "Command", I can say `Dim Command As Command`?

Comment: @DRoam Yes.  Variable names can be the same as type names without any issue.  The compiler knows, based on the context, whether you mean the type or the variable.

Comment: VB.Net allows the names to match, though it's not great practice. Better to give the variable a different name that also communicates some context. The example code using the Type name from the question would have been `Dim command As MyCommand` or `Dim commands As New List(Of MyCommand)`

Comment: Great tips, thanks. This is good to know. It'll be hard to break the hungarian notation habit but I'll do my best ;)